# Оптимизация css: в каких случаях используется class, а в каких id?

Tags: классы, css

Подскажите, нужно ли вот так объединять:

```
.top li,article,.top,.number,.comments{margin-bottom:10px}
```

И в каких случаях используется class, а в каких id? А то у меня в основном только class.

P.S. Может, от себя что-то посоветуете по оптимизации?

Comment: для оптимизации css очень много онлайн сервисов есть

Comment: @soledar10 ну охота еще понимать самому, а не просто готовым пользоваться.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/143452/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По своему опыту советую как можно реже использовать id.

Во-первых, на поздних этапах разработки у вас уже будет набор стилей, которые, возможно, захочется использовать на странице не единожды. В случае с id вам придется либо переписывать стили, либо дублировать их уже для классов.

Во-вторых, по личному опыту могу сказать, что иногда не замечаю, что, например, в jquery выборке машинально записываю точку вместо хеша $('.select') / $('#select'). И потом ищу "баг".

В третьих, точки выглядят аккуратнее, нежели хеши. И если я где-то использоавал Id в качестве родителя остальных стилей, то на таблицу потом не очень приятно смотреть.

Ну и как было сказано выше, id - это идентификатор элемента, поэтому он не должен повторяться. Этой логике нужно следовать, когда используешь id, но в конечном счете выделение уникальных элементов на странице таким способом не особо важная цель.

Comment: Однако, обращение из jQuery к классу (кроме случаев с each()) даст нам неопределенность. Соглашусь, что использовать ID нужно реже, как правило, только в этом случае и пользуюсь. То есть, **исключительно** для идентификации элемента.

Comment: А вот для таких случаев нужно вешать управляющие классы, которые не стилизуются в CSS а служат только для управления: `.js-btn-submit, .js-btn-callback` и тд.

Answer (score 2):

При вёрстке верстай всегда всё на классах. В своё время очень много это обсуждалось. Очевидно, что потом ты передашь это дело программисту и он уже где ему нужно поставит айдишники. Иначе вспомнит тебя не добрым словом.
А все эти семантические сказки про класс - это группа элементов, а id уникальный идентификатор, это всё словоблудие. Оставь это людям оторванным от реальной разработки.

Answer (score 1):

Наоборот, лучше разделять. id — это **идентификатор** элемента и он должен быть **уникальным** на странице. Класс — это набор элементов, которые объединяются общим набором стилей.

От себя советую для начала http://htmlbook.ru

Comment: @densmith объединение делается с помощью одного онлайн сервиса для оптимизации css, получается так лучше не делать? Я как понял: id если нужно какую то кнопку подсветить или еще какой то элемент что потом будет использоваться с помощью js, а class для всего основного.

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли. Оптимизация не помешает (хотя, на любителя дело), но уже лишь после того, как будет готова верстка. Иначе при увеличении количества строк кода однажды не получится разобраться, почему верстка плывет.

Answer (score 1):

- Использовать только классы
- Научитесь использовать "препроцессор", попробуйте, скажем его: http://compass-style.org и забудете про такие конструкции, как в ОП посте
- Использовать управляющие классы для JS, которые не зависят от стиля, элемента, места на странице.
- Про вложенность классов - ерунда. На современных устройствах сотые доли секунды. (я имею ввиду разумно конечно)
- Не используйте селектор `*`